# Unable to compile tshark static binary

Tags: cmake, wireshark, tshark

As per this [how-to-static-compile-tshark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67251370/how-to-static-compile-tshark), I am trying to do a build a static tshark binary that I can run on some other Linux system. But I am unable to find the configure file in the git repo for [wireshark](https://gitlab.com/wireshark/wireshark). The only building method supported is through `cmake`. But I do not see an option for doing static build with CMake.

What am I missing?